# How to set the value of a Date field from PHP?

Tags: datetime, custom-field

I'd like to set the value of a Date field from my custom PHP code.
How can this be made? Which format does the Date field expect when using the setValue() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example value that will set it to today:

```
[
  'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
  'date' => date('m/d/Y')
]
```

As always, easiest to find out how it's done by inspecting the fields as they are saved in the control panel.